# Share variable from .gs into .html in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to get respondents to a Google Form survey fill another survey, but some of their responses will be pre-filled based on the first survey. Basically, want all of their responses attached to the unique person, without making them answer same questions again. And it must be two surveys, not a continuation.
In this example, I'm only pre-filling their email address, but it may be more fields.

So in Google Apps Script, I've got a Code.gs and and Email1.html scripts as follows:

```
function confirmationEmail1(e) {
  
  var htmlBody= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Email1').getContent();
  var recipient=e.response.getRespondentEmail();
  if(recipient!==undefined){
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to:recipient,
      subject: 'Thank you. Please answer another one',
      htmlBody: htmlBody,
    })
  }
}
```

And the following email body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Thank you for filling the survey</p> 
    <p>Now fill another one. Some answers will be pre-filled based on your past responses<p> 
    <p>To continue click this <a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfqYWf-V0Jrwh8ld2AjuHtskuEHr1CfQB3_wrLS7grzZ_EajQ/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.786833434=<?= recipient ?>">Link</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong in this place  that it does not retrieve the recipient variable from Code.gs but simply pre-fills the text "" in my second survey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `htmlBody` is a string you can replace any text fragments with another text fragments, with `string.replace()` method.

Say you can make `{RECEPIENT}` in the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Thank you for filling the survey</p> 
    <p>Now fill another one. Some answers will be pre-filled based on your past responses<p> 
    <p>To continue click this <a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfqYWf-V0Jrwh8ld2AjuHtskuEHr1CfQB3_wrLS7grzZ_EajQ/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.786833434=<?={RECEPIENT}?>">Link</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And then replace the text `{RECEPIENT}` it with `recepient` value in the script:

```
function confirmationEmail1(e) {
  
  var htmlBody= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Email1').getContent();
  var recipient=e.response.getRespondentEmail();
  if(recipient!==undefined){

    htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{RECEPIENT}', recipient); // <--- here

    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to:recipient,
      subject: 'Thank you. Please answer another one',
      htmlBody: htmlBody,
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Yuri! This works perfectly and using this method I also managed to feed other responses from survey1 into the ThankYou email and into survey2.